# MEAN stack Angular service not being injected into application

Tags: node.js, angularjs, mean-stack, angularjs-injector

I am relatively new to MEAN stack development having been working with it for the past few months. I have an issue I am trying to resolve that I have been researching extensively but cannot seem to get to the bottom of.

So, I have a MEAN stack application that I scaffolded using Yeomen. I created a route which has a view that I would like to show a record set using Angulars ng-repeat directive. I get the dataset via an http get call via an Angular service. However, when I run the app using Grunt I get the error:

Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'Records' is not available!

I have put a reference to the service in my controller:

```
angular.module('recordsApp').controller('RecordsCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $filter, Records) {
```

I have also injected into it the app within the app.js file:

```
angular.module('recordsApp', [
'ngCookies',
'ngResource',
'ngSanitize',
'ngRoute',
'Records'
])
```

Can anyone please help point me in the right direction here as to what I am missing?

Thank you.

Comment: is `Records` a `module` or a `service` ?

Comment: Have you written Records service using angular.factory and make sure you have included that file too.

Comment: Hi @dark_ruby I have written Records as a service like so angular.module('recordsApp',[])
  .factory('Records', ['$http', function ($http) {
      return{
        getAllData : function(data) {
        return $http.get('/api/examplerecords', data);
      }
   }
}]);

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to include 'Records' module as your module dependancy, as you only have a service called `Records` in the same module

```
angular.module('recordsApp', [
'ngCookies',
'ngResource',
'ngSanitize',
'ngRoute'
])
```